# Sorting the unanswered questions by date, not by votes

Tags: support, unanswered-questions, sorting

Is there some way to do that? I mean, of course the most voted unanswered questions are quite interesting, but I would like to see the most recent unanswered questions instead.

Comment: You have several possibilities to view [unanswered questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/), for example [newest](http://math.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest) or [votes](http://math.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes) tab.

Comment: BTW if the solutions suggested in my comment and in Asaf's post are what you wanted, then probably ([meta-tag:support]) would be a better tag for your post than ([meta-tag:feature-request]).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search for `is:question answers:0` and sort by date.

As Martin suggests, `closed:0` will filter out the closed questions, which I presume are less of an interest for you.

Comment: Adding `closed:0` was suggested [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122898/an-option-to-display-newest-unanswered-questions/183987#183987).

Comment: You don't need `is:question` part; the parameter `answers:0` tells the system you are searching for questions.

Comment: @user103254: Interesting. I did not know that. I guess I never expected the search feature to be that clever... :\

Comment: It's sometimes too clever... `is:answer answers:0` also brings up unanswered questions, disregarding the instruction `is:answer`.